# Java - JPanel vs Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jpanel, awt

i'm learning java, and i'm planning to make a game with swing, but i have a few questions:

1. Iknow that i shouldnt mix awt and swing,but i read that canvas has active render and swing elements pasive render (you have to wait for the OS calling `paint()` or `paintComponent()`) and for a game is better to use active.What are the beneficts or advantages to use canvas over JPanel, or JPanel over Canvas?
2. What are the benefits between extending one of them (Canvas or JPanel classes) and instantiate them?
3. What are the differences between `Canvas.getBufferStrategy()`  and `JFrame.getBuffertrategy`?(i know that aren't static methods)
4. It's good to make a bufferStrategy into a JPanel or JComponent class to simulate active render (i know that swing components are implicitly doble-buffered)?

I searched these questions, but i didn't find a good reply.

Comment: My own experience is that a custom painted `JPanel` is fine for most animations (e.g. simple games).  OTOH it you really want to get serious about control of the screen, you might best look to [full screen exclusive mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/)..

Answer (score 0):

If you plan complex games I suggest not to use java2D or canvas. For little games like PingPong or something like that java2D is ok but you will notice that it gets very hard to achieve a constant 60 fps rate on more complex games. 
In case you plan a more complex game:
[LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

The advantage is that you can develop platform independent (Desktop, Android, IOS, Webbrowser)

Comment: First i want to develop games using "purely" java, but LibGDX is a good game-developing solution, thanks.